# The latest versioned LinkedIn API does not support projection

Tags: linkedin-api

I checked the latest versioned 202212 API with Postman. It shows "projection parameter is not allowed for this endpoint" error.

[202212 API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MoAG.png)

Nov and Dec versions do not support projection, but Jun to Oct versions do. However, Nov and Dec documentations still include projection page, which confuses me. Do it mean LinkedIn API will not support projection anymore? Or is it my request url issue? Are there any other ways to do projection?